# How to write php code inside javascript inner HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to write PHP code inside javascript inner HTML, I want to write PHP code inside javascript innerHTML that contain HTML code

```
<?php
<script>
document.getElementById("view-img-path"+id).innerHTML ="<input type='hidden' name='new-image-attachment-id' id='image-attachment-id' value='"<?php echo  get_option('media_selector_attachment_id'); ?>"'/>"
</script>
```

I want to write PHP code inside, is my code is correct it is showing error in my IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var option = '<?php echo  get_option('media_selector_attachment_id'); ?>';
    document.getElementById("view-img-path"+id).innerHTML ="<input type='hidden' name='new-image-attachment-id' id='image-attachment-id' value='+ option +'/>"
```

your code must be in .**php** file

Answer (score 1):

remove `"` outside php tag. Also remove `<?php` before `<script>`

```
<script>
document.getElementById("view-img-path"+id).innerHTML ="<input type='hidden' name='new-image-attachment-id' id='image-attachment-id' value='<?php echo  get_option('media_selector_attachment_id'); ?>'/>"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I Just Create One `.php` File and then using php code `Include` to include that php file in Js.

**myfile.php**

```
<input type='hidden' name='new-image-attachment-id' id='image-attachment-id' value='<?php $myvalue = get_option('media_selector_attachment_id');  echo $myvalue;  ?>
```

**HTML**

```
   <script>
      document.getElementById("view-img-path"+id).innerHTML ='<?php include_once "myfile.php";?>'
   </script>
```

> OR **( LiKe In Your Case )**

```
<script>

document.getElementById("view-img-path"+id).innerHTML ="<input type='hidden' name='new-image-attachment-id' id='image-attachment-id' value='<?php $myvalue = get_option('media_selector_attachment_id');  echo $myvalue;  ?>'/>"

</script
```

> OR

```
var option = '<?php echo  get_option('media_selector_attachment_id'); ?>';

document.getElementById("view-img-path"+id).innerHTML ="<input type='hidden' name='new-image-attachment-id' id='image-attachment-id' value='+ option +'/>"
```

Comment: I did not understand your answer, can you please explain it

Comment: `document.write()` ??